# why UICollectionView not calling didSelectItemAtIndexPath any more after scrolling the scrollView of it's cells?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiresponder

I am using the `UICollectionView` to display some products. In the custom `UICollectionViewCell`, there is a custom `UIScrollView`, where there are some images which allow the users to do a quick preview.

To forward tap gesture from the `UIScrollView` to the `UICollectionViewCell`, i override the touches related methods as below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        NSLog(@"Began ==>");
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        NSLog(@"Moved ==>");
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        NSLog(@"Ended ==>");
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        NSLog(@"Cancelled ==>");
        [self.nextResponder touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else {
        [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

sometimes it doesn't work in some cases. For example, when the `UICollectionView` is loaded first time, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method can be called when you tap, but after some scrolls or taps, the method is not called anymore, even if you try to reload the `UICollectionView`, it's still not working.

I try to log the message in the touch methods of `UICollectionViewCell`, the touches & event is forwarded. But why the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of `UICollectionView` is called if the cell get the gesture?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
1.the `UICollectionViewCell` is loaded from nib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's because of `self.dragging` understanding.
The correct way to forward the tap gesture is as below:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use nextResponder if you're targeting a specific object. As you've just witnessed, the responder chain can change and you may not always get the object you expect. Why this is happening here can be any number of reasons, but you should use a more reliable means in this situation anyways.

Since `UIScrollView` is a subview of the `UICollectionViewCell` you can just pass the event directly to your superview `[self.superview touchesMoved:touched withEvent:event];` You need to keep view hierarchy in mind when you're doing this and may have to call the superview's superview to reach the cell.

Also I wouldn't recommend using touches to intercept user interactions. I would highly recommend using UIGestureRecognizers as that will provide better more consistent functionality.

Comment: I try to use `self.superview`. it's also not reliable. Actually the gesture is forwarded to the cell. but the didselect method is not called. quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

You should always call the super methods.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Began ==>");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Moved ==>");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Ended ==>");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"Cancelled ==>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I mean, I knew it, but you made me check, and I was missing the `touchesCancelled` super call, which killed my touch handling randomly after scrolling around a bit. Presumably a touch was in a half-handled state.

Comment: Not true 

"if you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, if only as stub (empty) implementations."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621116-touchescancelled?language=objc

Comment: Not sure:

"If you override this method without calling super (a common use pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch events, if only as stub (empty) implementations."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621116-touchescancelled?language=objc

Comment: Not sure, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621116-touchescancelled?language=objc

Comment: Not true, if you don't call super one of them you must override the remaining and do the same (from apple docs).